# Is an iframe still a good idea?

Tags: iframe, blazor, domdocument

I have the requirement to be able to present a document on a website, in the browser. (not download it) and well the way I know to tackle this (without paying to third parties software) is an iframe, but that sounds like a really old practice.

I'm currently developing an application on Blazor and .net5 and sounds really wrong to put an iframe in there, can you guys provide me input for better practices or just your thoughts?

### Edit

I'm trying to use them to present doc, docx, pdf and pngs in a Blazor application with .net5.

Comment: I think you'd have a pretty hard time finding a modern web developer who recommends the use of iframes.  In Blazor, it seems to me that so long as you are the owner of the assets, you should be able to do whatever you were doing in an iframe in a nested Razor component.  Can you give a little more info on exactly what kind of document you are trying to present?

Comment: We currently got stored byte arrays, in a relational database, and we are trying to display the document beside some other information, as part of a page, because users want to be able to read some information provided to them with the document on the side. The documents are .pdfs, .docx, .doc (other office suite stuff), .png. extensions.

Comment: as you want to load .docx and etc iframe is a good choice. Yes you can use it. however there are modern and expensive components that you can use. but iframe is a safe and easy way.

Comment: Contrary to what @Bennyboy1973 says there are many valid reasons to use `iframe` in modern web development. One is separation of concerns. We run a white-label quoting service that other companies can embed in their own websites. Using an `iframe` on the parent site means both systems are completely independent. The company can use PHP, WordPress, Joomla, whatever for their hosting site, and our quoting service actually runs on Blazor Server.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected.  Developers of consumer sites would very much like to recommend that people use iframes to display their content without actually having any control over it.  But let me ask you a question-- in your white-label quoting service site, how many iframe embeds do YOU have?  :D

Comment: Well the thing is that after some research and due to the reality we don't have the budget to pay a monthly subscription to a 3rd party, I think iframe is the most realistic solution to the problem, also tried with object and embed elements, I think I will go with iFrame, and I found how to parse bytes to a format acceptable by src attribute of t.

Still looking for a work around for ms documents, but thanks for all your input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, after days of research, I'm trying to talk the team into the idea of creating an API dedicated to Docs, and as part of that effort would migrate documents to AWS S3 or azure blob storage.
We will introduce Aspose for rendering and separate the Issue.

Why? because all the solutions I have seen to support doc and Docx in .net5 are really hacky and I can see lacks in terms of security. And I would not recommend anyone to try to do the approach I was looking to do at the begging of this question.

I leave here what experience cause this research was pain and I hope this question can still help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I want to respond with a look from above. I manage a lot of sites, and I can say that I definitely do **not** recommend iframes, basically for 3 reasons

- it is slower to get up the development environment and debug problems
- all support cases or incidents from the page embedded in the iframe for the end user are from the parent page. At the ticket level you are filled with false positives.
- Browsers are becoming stricter with security and both sites, parent and embedded, must have the same security so that they are not marked as insecure